# Connect to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server hosted on a network. Windows authentication and SQL Server mode is enabled (both). I cannot connect

```
[DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
[DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
```

Can anybody suggest how to provide the server name when there exists a domain and please be explicit with slashes if any.

Comment: Can you quickly check if "SQL Server Browser" services is started on the server! go to Run and just type "services.msc". If not started, try starting this service and give a try!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your client is on the same network and all of the DNS records are working correctly (try pinging the server to see if it's available).

- You could try connecting using the IP address
- If you are trying to connect to a named instance use server\instance
- Check that you are not being blocked by the Windows Firewall on either your machine or the server (at the very least port 1433 will need to be open for a default SQL instance)

Comment: what is a named instance? and how can I check for firewall blocking? I can connect using the SQL server Managemnt GUI and I see the server as: hostname (SQL Server 8.0.2066 - domain\username)

Comment: follow-up question: when I send code the sql buffer, it runs, but it does not tell me command succesful/ rows affected etc.  <br/>  is there a way to get messages from the server displayed? selects are displayed ok.

Comment: IF it let you in with the IP but not the name then I would check your server resolves correctly in DNS by pinging it. How are you attempting to send the code? And what sort of command are you sending?

Comment: I am sending the code from an emacs buffer which holds a file with .sql extension by selecting and C-c C-r   the command is actually several commands part of a stored proc I am debugging. it does not echo the commands in the *SQL* buffer as it does when I connect to mySQL and there is no message regarding rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you enabled the following in Configuration Manager :

SQL Server Network Configuration
- Protocols 
--- TCP/IP - Enabled

SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit and 64bit)
- TCP/IP - Enabled
- Name Pipes - Enabled

and make sure SQL Server Instance is logged on as a domain account for you to be able to execute network backup.

try opening sql thru SSMS if named instance use IP/name of instance
else just the IP

and log in as "sa"

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled on port 1433 and named pipes are enabled. I do not understand: and make sure SQL Server Instance is logged on as a domain account for you to be able to execute network backup.

try opening sql thru SSMS if named instance use IP/name of instance else just the IP

Comment: services must be run under windows login.